# On a problem of sphere-packing for Reed-Solomon codes

Tags: probability, combinatorics, coding-theory

Suppose we have an $[n, k+1, n-k]$ Reed Solomon code $\mathcal C$ over $\mathbb F_q$, where $n-k=d$ is the minimum distance, and suppose that $d=2t+1$. We know that for every $r \in \mathbb F_q^n$ the ball 
$$ B(r,t):=\left\{x \in \mathbb F_q^n \;|\; d(x,r) \leq t \right\}$$
centered in $r$ with radius $t$ contains at most one codeword $c\in \mathcal C$. 
Obviously also the sphere
$$ S(r,t):=\left\{x \in \mathbb F_q^n \;|\; d(x,r) = t \right\}$$
has the same property.
( $d(-,-)$ is the Hamming distance).

Now fix an integer $e$ with $t<e<2t$
I have three questions.

Q1) I would like to know (or to estimate) the probability that, given an $r \in \mathbb F_q^n$, we have
$$ \left|B(r,e) \cap \mathcal C\right| \geq 2.$$
In particular I am interested in the case when $e=t+1$

Q2)  I would like to know (or to estimate) the probability that, given an $r \in \mathbb F_q^n$, we have
$$ \left|S(r,e) \cap \mathcal C\right| =1.$$
In particular I' d like to compute it when $e=t+1$

Q3) I want to estimate the expected value of :
  $$ \left|B(r,t+1)\cap \mathcal C\right|,\;\;\; \mbox{ and } $$
  $$ \left|S(r,t+1) \cap \mathcal C\right|$$
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Previously asked at http://mathoverflow.net/q/181577/12357

Comment: I tried to ask this question there yesterday, but no one is answering.

Comment: Look for a paper by E. R. Berlekamp in the May 1980 issue of the _Proceedings of the IEEE_ where he discusses the problem of decoding error patterns of weight $t+1$ with a Reed-Solomon code of minimum distance $2t+1$.